# How do we get to know whether a macro is present or not in a word document?

Tags: java, macros

Using java how to find whether a macro is present or not in a Microsoft word document. Tried using any switch command for WinWord.exe but there is no switch so that we can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library that can parse Word documents. [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is good choice as long as the documents aren't too big.

The library allows you to load the document. Afterwards, you can examine the various parts.

[Bug 52949](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52949) has an attachment with sample code how to extract Macro code. This should get you started.

You you're using the new XML format `.docx` / OOXML, then the word file is in fact a ZIP archive that you can unpack using the standard Java library. Inside, you will find a lot of XML files. The macros should be there as well.